# How to set up www cname for free dyndns subdomain

Tags: www, subdomain, url-rewriting, cname

I have a free dyndns domain

- mk12.gotdns.com

How can I set up a cname for

- www.mk12.gotdns.com

to point to mk12.gotdns.com?

And how can I force the www one, so that if you navigate to mk12.gotdns.com, it will go to the www one?

**Note:**
I don't mean html redirecting, but I think you can do it with url rewriting somehow, something like described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html). I've seen many tutorials, but they just vaguely say that you have to enter a cname record, I have no clue what file I need to put it in. Also, please see my question

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618998/apache-url-rewriting-wont-work

about getting url rewriting to work.

Comment: This answered question should help you: http://superuser.com/questions/127807/custom-personal-dyndns-solution/

Answer (score 1):

you would add the following to your DNS server:

```
www.mk12.gotdns.com 86400 CNAME mk12.gotdns.com
```

where:

- Host: www.mk12.gotdns.com
- TTL: 86400 (1 day in this case)
- Record Type: CNAME
- Data: mk12.gotdns.com