# How can I route a domain to my box at home?

Tags: dns, hosts, dynamic-ip, vps

I currently own my own domain, and have been using dyndns.com's "custom DNS" to allow me to redirect 'example.com' to my website at home, which is on a dynamic IP.

I've now switched over to a VPS solution which hosts my website and allows me root access to a box which will now host "example.com" on a static IP.

My question is, is it possible for me to somehow make "home.example.com" route to my box at home?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion (and what I do) would be to continue using DynDNS, and create a subdomain for `home.example.com` and make a `CNAME` to `myhouse.dyndns.com` (or whatever your DynDNS domain name is). This gives you the flexibility of using your own domain name with the ease of updating of DynDNS.

Personal example: (the .doesntexist.org address is my DynDNS address)
`0 09:37:13pm ~ $ dig woodcrest.thepurplepixel.org`

; <<>> DiG 9.4.3-P3 <<>> woodcrest.thepurplepixel.org
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28814
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;woodcrest.thepurplepixel.org.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
**woodcrest.thepurplepixel.org. 3600 IN CNAME   thepurplepixel.doesntexist.org.**
*thepurplepixel.doesntexist.org. 60 IN  A   174.93.79.144*

Comment: Brilliant.  I don't know why I didn't think about using a CNAME.  Cheap, too.

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

BIND already supports this. The IETF standards-track RFC 2136 defines the protocol and calls it "DNS UPDATE". Apple built the "Wide Area Bonjour" part of Bonjour on this (among other things). Mac OS X has a built-in client for this, and if your version of Windows doesn't have a built-in client, you can use "Bonjour for Windows". As a bonus, you can use all the other conveniences of Wide Area Bonjour. More information at http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerSetup.html